# Disable suhosin file permission check

Tags: file-permissions, php

I have just recently found out that suhosin makes sure not to execute php files with file permissions more open than 755.
However, I need to temporarily allow someone else FTP access to some files, so I'd need to chmod these to 777. That unfortunately makes the files non-executable by my PHP runtime.

Is there a way to bypass this check (temporarily)?

Answer (score 2):

Specify `suhosin.executor.include.allow_writable_files=1` in your `suhosin.ini` or `php.ini`, then reload your webserver / php daemon